# how to apply changes to datagridview without database vb

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim form As New form2
saleform.DataGridView3.Rows.Add(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text)
```

PS the code came from another form. The code works when it is on the same form as DataGridView, but doesn't work when used from the second form.

Comment: What does it error on? and is it trying to reference a Datagridview from another form?

Comment: it doesn't have an error but the values of the textboxes doesn't show up in the form where the datagridview is. I just want to see the values input from form2 textboxes to show up in form 1 in the datagridview

Comment: So saleform is the same as form 1 in your comment above? Is saleform its design time name or did you instantiate a new form like you did for `form` on your first line?

Answer (score 0):

On the form with the textboxes, declare a variable for each textbox, and set the variable to hold the textbox value.

- Eg; var1 = textbox1.Text
- var2 = textbox2.Text

Then, pass the variables in as parameters when loading the form. On the second form, declare a variable for each, and set the variables to be the same as the ones you passed in (But with different names, obviously). Then, use these variables in the add row code. (The variables need to be in the New sub of the second form)